# How to handle values greater than 255 as returned by toupper() in recent macOS with UTF-8 locales

Tags: c, macos, utf-8, locale

The problem, the code below is trying to address, is on how to effectively detect that an UTF-8 based locale might be in use so that all code points above 127 are not queried for `ctype` attributes, as we are dealing with plain (not wide) chars.

At least in macOS 14, when using an UTF-8 based locale. the following program will show 2 problematic code points that eventhough are valid for an unsigned char, are getting as a response from `toupper()` values that are not able to fit on that type:

```
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef WORKAROUND
static int is_utf8_locale(void)
{
        const char *charmap = nl_langinfo(CODESET);

        /* this shouldn't happen */
        if (!charmap)
                return 0;

        if (!strncmp(charmap, "UTF-8", 5))
                return 1;

        /*
         * nl_langinfo should never return an empty string, unless the "item" used is invalid, and it
         * should return the C/POSIX CODESET if the locale is missing one, but ...
         */
        if (!*charmap) {
                unsigned char buf[MB_CUR_MAX + 1];
                return (wctomb((char *)&buf, 0xf8ff) == 3) &&
                        (buf[0] == 0xef && buf[1] == 0xa3 && buf[2] == 0xbf);
        }

        return 0;
}
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        const char *locale = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "fr_FR";
        int i, f = 0;

        if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, locale))
                return 127;

#ifdef WORKAROUND
        if (is_utf8_locale())
                return 0;
#endif

        for (i = 128; i < 256; i++) {
                int u, l;
                unsigned char c = i;

                l = tolower(c);
                u = toupper(c);

                if (l > 255) {
                        int t = l % 256;
                        f++;
                        printf("tolower(%d) %c -> %d (%#x) %c\n", c, c, l, t, t);
                }
                if (u > 255) {
                        int t = u % 256;
                        f++;
                        printf("toupper(%d) %c -> %d (%#x) %c\n", c, c, u, t, t);
                }
        }
        return f;
}
```

The output (after some minor formatting) for the default fr_FR locale shows:

```
toupper(181) µ -> 924 (0x9c) <9c>
toupper(255) ÿ -> 376 (0x78) x
```

AFAIK, this change of behaviour for `toupper()` is somehow recent and at least wouldn't happen with 10.15, and while `toupper()` has been known to "sometimes" try to be more helpful (as a BSD extension), I couldn't see the problem in any recent BSD systems I tried, and they all mention that behaviour as deprecated, suggesting instead to use the wide char interfaces.

The "-DWORKAROUND" works but is IMHO too ugly and would be also problematic in a threaded environment, while being specially hacky because of the way macOS defines their locales.

All locales without a explicit `.${CHARMAP}` (which show the problematic response from `nl_langinfo()` described in the comments) as well as the ones that include `.UTF-8` and that use sometimes `.utf8` in other systems (allthough they always return the correct value from `nl_langinfo()` in those cases) seem to be affected.

The workaround obviously needs additional code for non POSIX systems.

The [affected](https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/pull/313) application doesn't support exotic multibyte encodings other than UTF-8, but the detection using `wctomb()` is fragile and might not work outside of Apple systems so suggestions or testing results are also appreciated.

Comment: [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) don't know anything about multibyte encodings, only single `char` characters.

Comment: `toupper`/`tolower` just does not work with anything besides ASCII (and some ASCII extensions, depending on the locale). If you don't fancy implementing the (significantly more complicated) correct logic for Unicode yourself you'll have to rely on a library like [ICU](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu/) for this.

Comment: the [bug](https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/pull/313) affected code that creates a character case equivalent table that is meant to be used ONLY with single byte encodings, hence why the fact that toupper() returns values higher than.255 based on some (probably incorrect) logic is the problem this was meant to solve.

Comment: @Cubic: `toupper` and `tolower` operate in characters in the currently set locale, per C 2018 7.4. ASCII has nothing to do with it; they work even if the C implementation uses EBCDIC or some other character encoding. The C standard does not even require that ASCII be used at all.

Comment: @CarloArenas, aside: `buf[0] == 0xef && buf[1] == 0xa3 && buf[2] == 0xbf` risks issues if not all 3 bytes set.  Suggest `if (wctomb((char *)&buf, 0xf8ff) ==3 && buf[0] == 0xef && buf[1] == 0xa3 && buf[2] == 0xbf);`.

Comment: A small `int main() { printf("%d\n", toupper(181)); }` looks like a better mcve. 181 is https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B5, with uppercase character https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+039C, so does that make toupper return wide character? I think this is a bug, as `toupper` should return a character for which `isupper` returns true, but then what does `isupper((unsigned char)toupper((unsigned char)181)))` is return?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem to me. What is the original, real-life problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: As I understand, the X problem was that PCRE2 is not working correctly for fr_FR locale when toupper returns value greater than 255. https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/pull/313 https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/pull/313/commits/71ec55e464713956ea9f83cb1bc3c6d495033103 . That is because pcre2_maketables uses an array of uint8_t. Or rather, this is rather because `isupper` implementation is invalid.

Comment: @KamilCuk Interesting. So `toupper` on MacOS is broken. The solution there looks perfectly OK, why invent another one?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI because eventhough using `pcre2_maketables()` with an UTF locale is discouraged, there is nothing preventing it, and that would result in tables with bogus values that could trigger other bugs.

Comment: This does not compute. The X problem is observed in a NON-utf8 locale, isn't it?

Comment: It is a little more complicated than that.  The point is that if you are using an UTF-8 locale and generate a non UTF-8 table with it, if you process a regex WITHOUT UTF/UCP mode, then  all the entries from that table will be used, even if they might be probably bogus.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI the X problem (where two unrelated characters were assued to be case equivalent) was only observed in that scenario (UTF-8 locale and no UTF/UCP mode). If the locale is NON-utf8 then the issue wouldn't happen.

Comment: @CarloArenas: could you please avoid non standard positional arguments in the test code?

Comment: I'm lost. Can you show the output of the program on Mac OS X using a UTF-8 based locale?

Comment: Sorry I mean the output for the entire table, not just for the two problematic codes. And for an iso-8859-1 based locale too, if they are different.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: shown in my own response, note that the ambuiguity for the two affected codepoints is also avoided if using an ISO locale instead.

Answer (score 3):

The C Standard does not explicitly specify that values returned by `toupper()` must be in the range of type `unsigned char` or the special value `EOF`, but the paragraphs hereunder seem to imply that they should:

> **7.4 Character handling `<ctype.h>`**
>
> The header `<ctype.h>` declares several functions useful for classifying and mapping characters. In all cases the argument is an `int`, the value of which shall be representable as an `unsigned char` or shall equal the value of the macro `EOF`. If the argument has any other value, the behavior is undefined.
>
> [...]
>
> **7.4.2.2 The `toupper` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <ctype.h>
> int toupper(int c);
> ```
>
> **Description**
> The `toupper` function converts a lowercase letter to a corresponding uppercase letter.
>
> **Returns**
> If the argument is a character for which `islower` is true and there are one or more corresponding characters, as specified by the current locale, for which `isupper` is true, the `toupper` function returns one of the corresponding characters (always the same one for any given locale); otherwise, the argument is returned unchanged.

This implies that `toupper(181)` either

- returns a *character* for which `isupper` returns non zero
- or returns 181

If `toupper` returns a value greater than `UCHAR_MAX` for an argument in the defined range, this is a **bug** that is indeed likely to cause further problems in many programs, such as this one: https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/pull/313

The problem is present on my system (macOS 13.4, Homebrew clang version 16.0.6, Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.5.0) as shown with the test program below:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *locale = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "fr_FR";
    int f = 0;

    if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, locale))
        return 127;

    printf("Testing locale %s:\n", locale);

    for (int c = 128; c < 256; c++) {
        int l = tolower(c);
        int u = toupper(c);

        if (l > 255) {
            char cbuf[MB_CUR_MAX];
            char lbuf[MB_CUR_MAX];
            cbuf[wctomb(cbuf, c)] = '\0';
            lbuf[wctomb(lbuf, l)] = '\0';
            printf("%d: %s  isupper(%d): %d  tolower(%d): %d, %s\n",
                   c, cbuf, c, isupper(c), c, l, lbuf);
            f++;
        }
        if (u > 255) {
            char cbuf[MB_CUR_MAX];
            char ubuf[MB_CUR_MAX];
            cbuf[wctomb(cbuf, c)] = '\0';
            ubuf[wctomb(ubuf, u)] = '\0';
            printf("%d: %s  islower(%d): %d  toupper(%d): %d, %s\n",
                   c, cbuf, c, islower(c), c, u, ubuf);
            f++;
        }
    }
    if (f) {
        printf("%d errors!\n", f);
    }
    return f;
}
```

Output in my system:

```
Testing locale fr_FR:
181: µ  islower(181): 1  toupper(181): 924, Μ
255: ÿ  islower(255): 1  toupper(255): 376, Ÿ
2 errors!
```

Looking at the source code for the Apple LibC, it seems they are trying to use the same tables for the `<ctype.h>` macros and wide character versions `towupper` and `towlower`, only rejecting argument values larger than `UCHAR_MAX`.  It so happens that `µ` and `ÿ` have an uppercase version in Unicode that is greater than `UCHAR_MAX` and should be returned by `towupper` for this locale, but should be ignored by `toupper`.  This is a **bug** in the implementation.

Comment: Is this locale UTF-8-based? Does tolower(192) return 224?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI even in 10.15 all those locales without a charset on their name where UTF-8 based, and indeed the fact this program succeeds in generating valid UTF-8 characters for printing would seem to indicate as much.

At least in macOS 14 with that locale tolower(192) -> 192

Comment: correction: tolower(192) -> 224

Comment: @CarloArenas so my conclusion is that  `toupper` and friends in these locales is totally broken on that system, not just for the two "problematic" values but for all non-ASCII (>127) values, and my answer applies.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: while I agree that the observed behaviour might be not within the specifications, I don't think it can be so easily ruled out as "completelly broken" (except for 181, which AFAIK is not `alpha` or `lower` in any locale with an ISO codeset)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: The problem is more subtle: `192`, which is `À` in **ISO8859-1** is an uppercase letter if this locale is selected and `tolower(192)` should return `224`, (`à`, the corresponding lowercase character), yet `toupper(181)` must not return a value greater than 255.  The problem is UTF-8 is not a single byte character set (it is not even a character set, but an encoding for Unicode) so byte values returned by `getchar()` in the range 128-255 do not correspond to *characters*, so the `isxxx()` functions should return `0` and `tolower()` and `toupper()` should return them unchanged.

Comment: @CarloArenas The behaviour is against the standard, and makes no sense. The `char` value of `192` does not correspond to any character at all, much less an uppercase or a lowercase letter, so the only acceptable behaviour as far as the standard goes is tolower(192) == toupper(192) == 192. Of course if you don't care about this you can do whatever you want.

Comment: We work in UTF-8. Why would we care what 192 means in ISO8859-1 any more than we care about what 192 means in EBCDIC? Actually ISO8859-1 is not even a player here. In that version of Mac OS X, the case tables seem to be built of *Unicode code points*. It just so happens that the first 256 Unicode code points coincide with ISO8859-1.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI: I do care, and indeed was close to accepting your answer, except that I think it is too drastic as the `ctype` functions are locale dependent and we shouldn't be calling them with values that aren't valid characters on that locale, to begin with IMHO.

Comment: @CarloArenas "we shouldn't be calling them with values that aren't valid characters on that locale" That's exactly NOT what the standard says. The standard says that values that do not correspond to uppercase/lowercase characters should be returned unchanged by tolower/toupper. *This is by design*. It is not easy (impossible, rather) for the user program to find out which bytes correspond to characters in the current locale. By contrast, it is trivial for tolower/toupper.

Comment: FWIW, I was wrong with my testing and it seems that even 10.15 is also affected, so the bug is not even that recent.

Answer (score 2):

> How to handle values greater than 255 as returned by toupper() in recent macOS with UTF-8 locales

It is impossible to handle values greater than 255 with `toupper` (on sane systems with a normal 8-bit char) in any locale and any system.

Comment: There was a time when "sane" and "8-bit" could be used in the same sentence about character encoding, but that was a long time ago. https://utf8everywhere.org/

Comment: @tripleee An 8-bit encoding and an 8-bit `char` are two completely different things.

Comment: The problem is not *to handle values greater than 255 with `toupper`*, which of course invoke undefined behavior on systems with 8-bit bytes, but *How to handle values greater than 255 **returned** by `toupper()`*, which seems to be a **BUG** in the macOS C library.

Answer (score 1):

The problem only exists on systems where `toupper` and/or friends are broken (not conforming to the C standard). Ergo, there is no need to detect a UTF-8 locale, there is a need to detect `toupper` that is broken.

If `toupper` returns a value >255 for any input, then it (and the whole `ctype` family) is broken (AFAICT not just for that input, but at least for all inputs >127). So if such value is detected, stop right there and reinitialise the whole upper part of the table.

You can even start with examining `toupper(181)`. If the value is greater than 255, you have broken `ctype`. This method only detects this particular `libc` bug, but you cannot hope to detect *every possible* bug. Detect and work around those you know about.

Answer (score 0):

Using a debug tool derived from the code proposed by @chqrlie and who validated the bogus `isupper()` responses where also happening in macOS 13 and are likely because of an implementation bug on that function, it would seem that the best option is to do a narrow workaround that ignores the bogus values and that keeps the function somehow closer to the standard, as implemented [already](https://github.com/PCRE2Project/pcre2/commit/8d3e96ceae6e5931444d461b6acea47ee1a8bed6).

The code:

```
#include <langinfo.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const char *locale = (argc > 1) ? argv[1] : "fr_FR";
    int verbose = (argc > 2);
    int f = 0, c;

    if (!setlocale(LC_CTYPE, locale)) {
        printf("usage: %s [<locale>] [-v]\n", argv[0]);
        printf("\tlocale defaults to fr_FR\n");
        printf("\t-v prints all characters with mappings\n");
        return 127;
    }

    printf("Testing locale %s with charmap \"%s\":\n", locale, nl_langinfo(CODESET));

    for (c = 128; c < 256; c++) {
        char cbuf[MB_CUR_MAX];
        char buf[MB_CUR_MAX];
        int bug = 0;
        int l = tolower(c);
        int u = toupper(c);

        cbuf[wctomb(cbuf, c)] = '\0';
        if (l > 255) {
            buf[wctomb(buf, l)] = '\0';
            printf("%x: %s  isupper(%d): %d  tolower(%d): %d, %s (tolower bug)\n",
                   c, cbuf, c, isupper(c), c, l, buf);
            bug++;
        }
        if (u > 255) {
            buf[wctomb(buf, u)] = '\0';
            printf("%x: %s  islower(%d): %d  toupper(%d): %d, %s (toupper bug)\n",
                   c, cbuf, c, islower(c), c, u, buf);
            bug++;
        }
        if (verbose && !bug) {
            if (l != c) {
                buf[wctomb(buf, l)] = '\0';
                printf("%x: %s  isupper(%d): %d  tolower(%d): %d, %s\n",
                       c, cbuf, c, isupper(c), c, l, buf);
            }
            if (u != c) {
                buf[wctomb(buf, u)] = '\0';
                printf("%x: %s  islower(%d): %d  toupper(%d): %d, %s\n",
                       c, cbuf, c, islower(c), c, u, buf);
            }
        }
        if (bug) {
            f += bug;
            bug = 0;
        }
    }

    if (f)
        printf("%d errors!\n", f);

    return f;
}
```

With the following output in macOS 14 for 3 french locales (the default one is identical to `fr_FR.UTF-8`, except from the "unspecified" charmap as described in the original code)

```
% ./x fr_FR.UTF-8 -v                                     
Testing locale fr_FR.UTF-8 with charmap "UTF-8":
b5: µ  islower(181): 1  toupper(181): 924, Μ (toupper bug)
c0: À  isupper(192): 1  tolower(192): 224, à
c1: Á  isupper(193): 1  tolower(193): 225, á
c2: Â  isupper(194): 1  tolower(194): 226, â
c3: Ã  isupper(195): 1  tolower(195): 227, ã
c4: Ä  isupper(196): 1  tolower(196): 228, ä
c5: Å  isupper(197): 1  tolower(197): 229, å
c6: Æ  isupper(198): 1  tolower(198): 230, æ
c7: Ç  isupper(199): 1  tolower(199): 231, ç
c8: È  isupper(200): 1  tolower(200): 232, è
c9: É  isupper(201): 1  tolower(201): 233, é
ca: Ê  isupper(202): 1  tolower(202): 234, ê
cb: Ë  isupper(203): 1  tolower(203): 235, ë
cc: Ì  isupper(204): 1  tolower(204): 236, ì
cd: Í  isupper(205): 1  tolower(205): 237, í
ce: Î  isupper(206): 1  tolower(206): 238, î
cf: Ï  isupper(207): 1  tolower(207): 239, ï
d0: Ð  isupper(208): 1  tolower(208): 240, ð
d1: Ñ  isupper(209): 1  tolower(209): 241, ñ
d2: Ò  isupper(210): 1  tolower(210): 242, ò
d3: Ó  isupper(211): 1  tolower(211): 243, ó
d4: Ô  isupper(212): 1  tolower(212): 244, ô
d5: Õ  isupper(213): 1  tolower(213): 245, õ
d6: Ö  isupper(214): 1  tolower(214): 246, ö
d8: Ø  isupper(216): 1  tolower(216): 248, ø
d9: Ù  isupper(217): 1  tolower(217): 249, ù
da: Ú  isupper(218): 1  tolower(218): 250, ú
db: Û  isupper(219): 1  tolower(219): 251, û
dc: Ü  isupper(220): 1  tolower(220): 252, ü
dd: Ý  isupper(221): 1  tolower(221): 253, ý
de: Þ  isupper(222): 1  tolower(222): 254, þ
e0: à  islower(224): 1  toupper(224): 192, À
e1: á  islower(225): 1  toupper(225): 193, Á
e2: â  islower(226): 1  toupper(226): 194, Â
e3: ã  islower(227): 1  toupper(227): 195, Ã
e4: ä  islower(228): 1  toupper(228): 196, Ä
e5: å  islower(229): 1  toupper(229): 197, Å
e6: æ  islower(230): 1  toupper(230): 198, Æ
e7: ç  islower(231): 1  toupper(231): 199, Ç
e8: è  islower(232): 1  toupper(232): 200, È
e9: é  islower(233): 1  toupper(233): 201, É
ea: ê  islower(234): 1  toupper(234): 202, Ê
eb: ë  islower(235): 1  toupper(235): 203, Ë
ec: ì  islower(236): 1  toupper(236): 204, Ì
ed: í  islower(237): 1  toupper(237): 205, Í
ee: î  islower(238): 1  toupper(238): 206, Î
ef: ï  islower(239): 1  toupper(239): 207, Ï
f0: ð  islower(240): 1  toupper(240): 208, Ð
f1: ñ  islower(241): 1  toupper(241): 209, Ñ
f2: ò  islower(242): 1  toupper(242): 210, Ò
f3: ó  islower(243): 1  toupper(243): 211, Ó
f4: ô  islower(244): 1  toupper(244): 212, Ô
f5: õ  islower(245): 1  toupper(245): 213, Õ
f6: ö  islower(246): 1  toupper(246): 214, Ö
f8: ø  islower(248): 1  toupper(248): 216, Ø
f9: ù  islower(249): 1  toupper(249): 217, Ù
fa: ú  islower(250): 1  toupper(250): 218, Ú
fb: û  islower(251): 1  toupper(251): 219, Û
fc: ü  islower(252): 1  toupper(252): 220, Ü
fd: ý  islower(253): 1  toupper(253): 221, Ý
fe: þ  islower(254): 1  toupper(254): 222, Þ
ff: ÿ  islower(255): 1  toupper(255): 376, Ÿ (toupper bug)
2 errors!
% ./x fr_FR.ISO8859-1 -v | iconv -f LATIN1 -t UTF-8      
Testing locale fr_FR.ISO8859-1 with charmap "ISO8859-1":
c0: À  isupper(192): 1  tolower(192): 224, à
c1: Á  isupper(193): 1  tolower(193): 225, á
c2: Â  isupper(194): 1  tolower(194): 226, â
c3: Ã  isupper(195): 1  tolower(195): 227, ã
c4: Ä  isupper(196): 1  tolower(196): 228, ä
c5: Å  isupper(197): 1  tolower(197): 229, å
c6: Æ  isupper(198): 1  tolower(198): 230, æ
c7: Ç  isupper(199): 1  tolower(199): 231, ç
c8: È  isupper(200): 1  tolower(200): 232, è
c9: É  isupper(201): 1  tolower(201): 233, é
ca: Ê  isupper(202): 1  tolower(202): 234, ê
cb: Ë  isupper(203): 1  tolower(203): 235, ë
cc: Ì  isupper(204): 1  tolower(204): 236, ì
cd: Í  isupper(205): 1  tolower(205): 237, í
ce: Î  isupper(206): 1  tolower(206): 238, î
cf: Ï  isupper(207): 1  tolower(207): 239, ï
d0: Ð  isupper(208): 1  tolower(208): 240, ð
d1: Ñ  isupper(209): 1  tolower(209): 241, ñ
d2: Ò  isupper(210): 1  tolower(210): 242, ò
d3: Ó  isupper(211): 1  tolower(211): 243, ó
d4: Ô  isupper(212): 1  tolower(212): 244, ô
d5: Õ  isupper(213): 1  tolower(213): 245, õ
d6: Ö  isupper(214): 1  tolower(214): 246, ö
d8: Ø  isupper(216): 1  tolower(216): 248, ø
d9: Ù  isupper(217): 1  tolower(217): 249, ù
da: Ú  isupper(218): 1  tolower(218): 250, ú
db: Û  isupper(219): 1  tolower(219): 251, û
dc: Ü  isupper(220): 1  tolower(220): 252, ü
dd: Ý  isupper(221): 1  tolower(221): 253, ý
de: Þ  isupper(222): 1  tolower(222): 254, þ
e0: à  islower(224): 1  toupper(224): 192, À
e1: á  islower(225): 1  toupper(225): 193, Á
e2: â  islower(226): 1  toupper(226): 194, Â
e3: ã  islower(227): 1  toupper(227): 195, Ã
e4: ä  islower(228): 1  toupper(228): 196, Ä
e5: å  islower(229): 1  toupper(229): 197, Å
e6: æ  islower(230): 1  toupper(230): 198, Æ
e7: ç  islower(231): 1  toupper(231): 199, Ç
e8: è  islower(232): 1  toupper(232): 200, È
e9: é  islower(233): 1  toupper(233): 201, É
ea: ê  islower(234): 1  toupper(234): 202, Ê
eb: ë  islower(235): 1  toupper(235): 203, Ë
ec: ì  islower(236): 1  toupper(236): 204, Ì
ed: í  islower(237): 1  toupper(237): 205, Í
ee: î  islower(238): 1  toupper(238): 206, Î
ef: ï  islower(239): 1  toupper(239): 207, Ï
f0: ð  islower(240): 1  toupper(240): 208, Ð
f1: ñ  islower(241): 1  toupper(241): 209, Ñ
f2: ò  islower(242): 1  toupper(242): 210, Ò
f3: ó  islower(243): 1  toupper(243): 211, Ó
f4: ô  islower(244): 1  toupper(244): 212, Ô
f5: õ  islower(245): 1  toupper(245): 213, Õ
f6: ö  islower(246): 1  toupper(246): 214, Ö
f8: ø  islower(248): 1  toupper(248): 216, Ø
f9: ù  islower(249): 1  toupper(249): 217, Ù
fa: ú  islower(250): 1  toupper(250): 218, Ú
fb: û  islower(251): 1  toupper(251): 219, Û
fc: ü  islower(252): 1  toupper(252): 220, Ü
fd: ý  islower(253): 1  toupper(253): 221, Ý
fe: þ  islower(254): 1  toupper(254): 222, Þ
% ./x fr_FR.ISO8859-15 -v | iconv -f ISO8859-15 -t UTF-8 
Testing locale fr_FR.ISO8859-15 with charmap "ISO8859-15":
a6: Š  isupper(166): 1  tolower(166): 168, š
a8: š  islower(168): 1  toupper(168): 166, Š
b4: Ž  isupper(180): 1  tolower(180): 184, ž
b8: ž  islower(184): 1  toupper(184): 180, Ž
bc: Œ  isupper(188): 1  tolower(188): 189, œ
bd: œ  islower(189): 1  toupper(189): 188, Œ
be: Ÿ  isupper(190): 1  tolower(190): 255, ÿ
c0: À  isupper(192): 1  tolower(192): 224, à
c1: Á  isupper(193): 1  tolower(193): 225, á
c2: Â  isupper(194): 1  tolower(194): 226, â
c3: Ã  isupper(195): 1  tolower(195): 227, ã
c4: Ä  isupper(196): 1  tolower(196): 228, ä
c5: Å  isupper(197): 1  tolower(197): 229, å
c6: Æ  isupper(198): 1  tolower(198): 230, æ
c7: Ç  isupper(199): 1  tolower(199): 231, ç
c8: È  isupper(200): 1  tolower(200): 232, è
c9: É  isupper(201): 1  tolower(201): 233, é
ca: Ê  isupper(202): 1  tolower(202): 234, ê
cb: Ë  isupper(203): 1  tolower(203): 235, ë
cc: Ì  isupper(204): 1  tolower(204): 236, ì
cd: Í  isupper(205): 1  tolower(205): 237, í
ce: Î  isupper(206): 1  tolower(206): 238, î
cf: Ï  isupper(207): 1  tolower(207): 239, ï
d0: Ð  isupper(208): 1  tolower(208): 240, ð
d1: Ñ  isupper(209): 1  tolower(209): 241, ñ
d2: Ò  isupper(210): 1  tolower(210): 242, ò
d3: Ó  isupper(211): 1  tolower(211): 243, ó
d4: Ô  isupper(212): 1  tolower(212): 244, ô
d5: Õ  isupper(213): 1  tolower(213): 245, õ
d6: Ö  isupper(214): 1  tolower(214): 246, ö
d8: Ø  isupper(216): 1  tolower(216): 248, ø
d9: Ù  isupper(217): 1  tolower(217): 249, ù
da: Ú  isupper(218): 1  tolower(218): 250, ú
db: Û  isupper(219): 1  tolower(219): 251, û
dc: Ü  isupper(220): 1  tolower(220): 252, ü
dd: Ý  isupper(221): 1  tolower(221): 253, ý
de: Þ  isupper(222): 1  tolower(222): 254, þ
e0: à  islower(224): 1  toupper(224): 192, À
e1: á  islower(225): 1  toupper(225): 193, Á
e2: â  islower(226): 1  toupper(226): 194, Â
e3: ã  islower(227): 1  toupper(227): 195, Ã
e4: ä  islower(228): 1  toupper(228): 196, Ä
e5: å  islower(229): 1  toupper(229): 197, Å
e6: æ  islower(230): 1  toupper(230): 198, Æ
e7: ç  islower(231): 1  toupper(231): 199, Ç
e8: è  islower(232): 1  toupper(232): 200, È
e9: é  islower(233): 1  toupper(233): 201, É
ea: ê  islower(234): 1  toupper(234): 202, Ê
eb: ë  islower(235): 1  toupper(235): 203, Ë
ec: ì  islower(236): 1  toupper(236): 204, Ì
ed: í  islower(237): 1  toupper(237): 205, Í
ee: î  islower(238): 1  toupper(238): 206, Î
ef: ï  islower(239): 1  toupper(239): 207, Ï
f0: ð  islower(240): 1  toupper(240): 208, Ð
f1: ñ  islower(241): 1  toupper(241): 209, Ñ
f2: ò  islower(242): 1  toupper(242): 210, Ò
f3: ó  islower(243): 1  toupper(243): 211, Ó
f4: ô  islower(244): 1  toupper(244): 212, Ô
f5: õ  islower(245): 1  toupper(245): 213, Õ
f6: ö  islower(246): 1  toupper(246): 214, Ö
f8: ø  islower(248): 1  toupper(248): 216, Ø
f9: ù  islower(249): 1  toupper(249): 217, Ù
fa: ú  islower(250): 1  toupper(250): 218, Ú
fb: û  islower(251): 1  toupper(251): 219, Û
fc: ü  islower(252): 1  toupper(252): 220, Ü
fd: ý  islower(253): 1  toupper(253): 221, Ý
fe: þ  islower(254): 1  toupper(254): 222, Þ
ff: ÿ  islower(255): 1  toupper(255): 190, Ÿ
```

Comment: Sigh. What does `wctomb` do in a program that does not input, output, or process any wide characters? Why do you associate 254 with þ and 255 with ÿ? These associations only hold in encodings that are not in use by this program, like UCS-4. What does UCS-4 have to do with what you are doing, which is AFAICT processing UTF-8 strings? Why not check what characters have these codes in EBCDIC or ISO-8859-5 or any other encoding that comes to your mind?

Comment: The good thing (but also the sad thing, depending on how you look at it) is that you are going to get away with this, because (AFAICT) there happens to be no pair of valid UTF-8 strings (other than ASCII ones of course) that are mapped to each other with this buggy implementation of tolower/toupper. So people trying to do case-insensitive regex matching are unlikely to be affected if both the regex and the target string are valid UTF-8.  This is a sheer coincidence though. Of course this implementation will happily map a valid UTF-8 string to an invalid one.